# Kendo UI CurrencyTextBox styling vs. @Html.EditorFor styling with k-textbox class

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and the Kendo UI CurrencyTextBox to help with the display of numbers on form on a view. Kendo do not supply standard textbox controls, so for non number textboxes, I use @Html.EditorFor. Kendo supply a number of 'themes' contained within css, I am using kendo.default.min.css. Clearly I want my form to look consistent and have all controls (Kendo or not) looking the same. Reading a similar post, Telerik staff suggested adding the "k-textbox" class to the textbox, as we are using EditorFor and not TextboxFor, we cannot apply HTMLAttributes directly, but we can wrap the field in a div so that it can inherit the style.

The code of the view is below:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.illus_LoanAmount)
    @(Html.Kendo().CurrencyTextBoxFor(m => m.illus_LoanAmount)
    .Spinners(false)
    .Format("{0:£#,##0;(£#,##0)}"))    

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.illus_LoanAmount)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.illus_RepaymentType)
    <div class="k-textbox">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.illus_RepaymentType)
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.illus_RepaymentType)
</div>
```

The below looks 'sort' of right, but is by no means pixel perfect and thus can go nowhere near production. I made sure this was not a result of my own css, and also tried inline styles with TextboxFor, still no luck.

[image: Fields looking not quite right]

My solution is to strip the Kendo CSS styles out entirely - but this seems like a bit of a shame. Does anyone have experience at making standard controls dress up like Kendo/Telerik ones?